# Find intermediate points to avoid circle obstacle in path

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I have two points $P_1$ and $P_2$, as well as a circle with radius $r$ centered at $C$. All three points are at arbitrary positions.
I want to go from $P_1$ to $P_2$ **without** crossing through the circle.

For that reason, another point $P_3$ is needed as an intermediary. This can be any of two points (shown in the image as $P_3$ and $P_4$) **How do I obtain their coordinates?** I attach a picture to aid in the explanation.

[image]

Edit 1: I suppose it is obtained as the *intersection* between the tangents from $P_1$ and $P_2$ but am not entirely sure on how to.

Edit 2: Assume the circle *always* interferes with the path, even if slightly.

Edit 3: The radius $r$ of the circle is given.

Comment: Are you given the radius of the circle?

Comment: Ohh, left out that detail. Yes, I am given the radius of the circle.

Comment: Well, to start, the slope of a circle centered at the origin at any point is $\frac{x}{y}$…

Comment: You might want to consider showing your work on the problem.

Comment: SORRY, the slope is $-\frac{x}{y}$!

Comment: If one will solve this problem with construction, one will first draw circle with diameter $P_iC$, then find its intersections $K_{ij}$ with circle $C$. Then one can find intersection of $P_1K_{1j}$ and $P_2K_{2j}$ to obtain $P_3$ or $P_4$. One can do the same with formulae. First find $L_i$ which is middle of $P_iC$. Then find distance $L_iC$. Then write circle equation with center $L_i$ and radius equal to $L_iC$. Then write circle equation with center $C$ and radius $r$. Then find intersections from simultaneous equations of circles. Then find $P_3$ and $P_4$ from equations of lines.

Comment: Note that shortest path includes curved part.

Answer (score 1):

After trying for a while, I found a possible solution. I leave it here in case it helps anyone :)

### Getting tangent points from $P_1$ to circle.

To aid in the process, let's center the circle to the origin (subtract coordinates from all points).
As shown in the image below, a right angle triangle can be formed with the vertices of the circle center, the point ($P_1$) and the tangent point ($Q$).

[image]

1. Using simple trigonometry we can find the value of $\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$, where $d$ is the distance between the center and $P_1$.
2. Furthermoe, the angle $\phi$ can be found using the components of $P_1$, such that $\phi = \arctan\left(\frac{y_1}{x_1}\right)$.
3. The points are then generated:
   $$Q_1 = \left( \frac{x_1}{|x_1|}r\cos(\theta + \phi), \frac{x_1}{|x_1|}r\sin(\theta + \phi) \right)$$
   $$Q_2 = \left( \frac{x_1}{|x_1|}r\cos(\theta - \phi), \frac{x_1}{|x_1|}r\sin(\theta - \phi) \right)$$
4. After restoring the coordinate system, the equations of lines $Q_1P_1$ and $Q_2P_1$ can be found.

### Further steps

The problem is then reduced to: **find the intersection points of both pairs of tangent lines**.
The tricky part might be finding out which pairs to compare. Perhaps there is an even better solution for this second phase.

Answer (score 0):

Building on edvilme’s approach, we can turn this problem into a system of equations. This one is just for P3, but you can mirror the approach for P4. $x_{13}$, $y_{13}$, $y_{23}$, and $x_{23}$ are the coordinates of the points where the tangent lines intersect the circle, which are not given, and $x_3$ and $y_3$ are the coordinates of P3. Here is the system of equations:$$x_{13}^2+y_{13}^2=r^2$$
$$x_{23}^2+y_{23}^2=r^2$$
$$(x_{13}-x_1)^2+(y_{13}-y_1)^2=x_1^2+y_1^2-r$$
$$(x_{23}-x_2)^2+(y_{23}-y_2)^2=x_2^2+y_2^2-r$$
$$y_1+(x_3-x_1)(\frac{y_1-y_{13}}{x_1-x_{13}})=y_2+(x_3-x_2)(\frac{y_{23}-y_2}{x_{23}-x_2})$$
$$y_3=y_1+(x_3-x_1)(\frac{y_1-y_{13}}{x_1-x_{13}})$$
Some easy mental math for you :).